# Why docker working directory isn't affected

Tags: node.js, docker, command, dockerfile

[image]

As you see I have a directory called `node-web-app` inside it I have two directories

- the second one called `workdir`
- the first one called `app` which contain nodejs code, and I want dockerizing it

this is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /d/project/node-web-app/workdir

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

as I understand this commands `COPY` `RUN` `CMD` will be executed in the specified working directory

(in my case the working directory called `workdir` which is the second directory in `node-web-app` and its path is `/d/project/node-web-app/workdir` )

---

when I build the image from that `Dockerfile` the build done successfully, after that I checked the specified working directory (`/d/project/node-web-app/workdir`). **the problem is** it doesn't have `app` files which should be copied using `COPY` command.

**my question** is this problem: bug in docker or my understanding of `WORKDIR` command is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything fine with your docker file 
You need check inside the docker container

First run the container

```
docker run -it -d --name test yourImage
```

Now access the docker container

```
docker exec -it test bash
```

now we enter into docker container check project files in current directory

```
ls
```

you will see the your project files

Comment: so the working directory exists in **docker container** not in the **local disk**. is that right?

Comment: yes when you build the docker image all the code will packed into your image, so now your image will work as your code and project required tools. 
When you run image then image will use your softwares and code

Answer (score -2):

Try below this should work as it is located into d: drive:

```
WORKDIR D:\\project\\node-web-app\\workdir
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile